# Record audio on frontend send to backend for Google Speech API call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-speech-api

I am trying to build what I thought was simple functionality into a website that I am building with ReactJS and Express for backend. But it's turning out to be much more difficult than I thought at first.

Essentially what I want is to have a button on the frontend that begins and ends a recording of the user's voice. Then I'd like to take that audio and send it to the server from which I make an API call to Google's Speech2Text API to get the text. My problem is two-fold, first of all which library do you recommend in order to do the recording? I used RecorderJS at first but after following the steps and converting the data into what I thought was the right format (16-signed bit linear PCM) when I send it and save it I get garbage and not what I recorded. Now I am trying to use the node-recorder-lpcm16 library which records with precisely the encoding that I need, however I am not sure if I am running it correctly since in the docs they write them for node such as

```
recorder = require('node-recorder-lpcm16');
recorder.record();
```

But what I do in my React code is:

```
import recorder from 'node-record-lpcm16';
...
onButtonPress() {
    recorder.record();
```

And I am not getting an error on the import statement, but I am getting an error on the record() call. The error that I am getting is `Uncaught Error: No such recorder found: sox`, but in my config I am not passing sox as the recordProgram but 'rec', not to mention I have sox installed both with `brew install sox` and with `npm install sox` in the frontend directory.

Secondly, I am not 100% the best way to send the audio to the server. Right now I am taking my buffer, sending it as a comma-separated string using a POST request; and on the server side splitting the string by commas and casting it as the correct array. However this isn't viable for longer recordings and I am wandering if there is a way I can stream it somehow, and what libs or tools I should use for this. For example in the google speech docs they have an example using the node-lpcm library that goes like this:

```
const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
const recognizeStream = client
  .streamingRecognize(request)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', data => {whatever});
recorder
  .record({
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    threshold: 0,
    recordProgram: 'rec'
  })
  .stream()
  .on('error', console.error)
  .pipe(recognizeStream);
```

And I am wondering how I set up this type of piping from client to server? Do I have to send a POST request each time on('data') or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Sorry for the length and thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?